# Match a substring of matched string in regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, find, replace

I can match the first line and open `div#someId input {` in the text:

```
div#someId input
{
padding-left: 2px;
border: 0;
background-color: white;
}
```

using: `(^div#.*input$\n)\{`

However, I want to match only the `{`, since I want to insert some CSS rules below by replacing `{` with e.g. `{\nheight: 100%;`

I using the Visual Studio Find and Replace dialog so I'm not able to create any variables or execute anything other than regex (that I'm aware of), so I assume the answer will be regex only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a group reference. `\0` stores the entire match, and you can use it in your replacementment.

**Edit** *escaping the `#` based on Alan Moore's comment*

```
search:   ^div\#.*input$\n\{
replace:  \0\nheight: 100%;
```

Comment: +1.  I can't tell if you're aware of this (since your solution works), but Visual Studio has [its own regex flavor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28VS.80%29.aspx), with several major differences from most other flavors.  For example, the `#` in your regex should have been escaped because it's a quantifier, equivalent to `+?` in most flavors (i.e., one or more, reluctantly).

Comment: @Alan No, I wasn't aware. I just took the OP's regex for the search which he said worked. Thank you, I will edit to something a little better.